# How to dump SQL query result from LookUp activity into a dict or array variable?

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image]
like this process or others, read SQL query result and set into a collection variable.

Add dynamic content but failed

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample SQL table:

[image]

Use lookup activity and give your SQL query in query option like below sample.

[image]

> read SQL query result and set into a collection variable.

Lookup will give the query result as array of objects. Give this array to array variable in set variable activity.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]